# Parameter tuning in lars (lasso) matlab

Tags: regression, matlab, lasso, lars

I am trying to use lars (matlab implementation:http://www.ece.ubc.ca/~xiaohuic/code/LARS/LARS.htm).

I want to do a leave one out cross validation on my data using this code. I have the following doubts:
This code has a parameter t, is this the parameter which has to be tuned during cross validation? If it is not given, the default is taken to be infinity. 
And the coefficients (weight matrix) is calculated to be of arbitrary dimension.

Can somebody help me understand whats going on in this code? I would like to perform a leave one out cross validation on my data using lars.

**EDIT**

I am also trying to use lasso function in-built with MATLAB. It has an option to perform cross validation. It outputs B and Fit Statistics, where B is Fitted coefficients, a p-by-L matrix, where p is the number of predictors (columns) in X, and L is the number of Lambda values.

Now given a new test sample, how can I calculate the output using this model?

Thanks